# Custom built computer with ASUS R9 290 GPU will not install video drivers without crashing

Tags: windows-8, drivers, graphics-card, crash, display-driver

I have a custom built computer with an [ASUS R9 290](https://www.asus.com/Graphics-Cards/R9290DC2OC4GD5/), an [ASUS Maximus VI Hero](https://www.asus.com/us/ROG_ROG/MAXIMUS_VI_HERO/) motherboard, and an an Intel Core i7 4770K running Windows 8.1 64-bit.

Recently I decided to wipe all my data to “start fresh.” After I had done so and had installed Windows, it was showing the screen in very bad quality. I couldn’t turn up my monitor to its native resolution.

So I tried to install the latest AMD Catalyst drivers, but it crashed as soon as the video driver part started installing. Afterwards, I went to the ASUS site and tried installing their drivers. It didn’t work the first time, but when I disabled the Catalyst Control Center install, it worked.

However, after about a minute—or when a program opens—the computer just blackscreens. Sometimes it recovers and sometimes it gives me a frozen screen with random purple dots. I don’t know what to do, can someone give me pointers?

Comment: Is there anything else that you have tried? Have you attempted to re-install the AMD Catalyst drivers a second time?

Also, what do you mean by 'very bad quality' in terms of the monitor? Were there any lines/patches of solid colours/areas not being displayed?